# How can I use a saved file variable in separate shells?

Tags: jenkins

I'm wondering how I can use this `csvfile` file saved via python:

```
csvfile = open("/tmp/" + ip + "-report.csv", "w")
    csvfile.write(report.text)
    csvfile.close()
```

to then be used in the next executed shell which is in cURL:

```
curl -u $PLATFORM_CREDS -XPUT https://domain.url.test/directory/savetohere -T $filename
```

How can I make `csvfile` a global variable to be used in other shell executables?

Comment: Can you share the full Pipeline?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a noob. Is there an easy way to get the full pipeline? I'm using freestyle project.

Comment: I'm afraid, it's not possible in Freestyle. You should be able to use Env Inject plugin and save values to environment variables and use.